# Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

While I am returning reduce sum to td(i.e. In React jsx), typescript is throwing error

```
TS2322: Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

// Code below

```
const data =['3','44','55']

<tr className='Table-row-1'>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td >
                {data.reduce((add: number, cur) => {
                  return add + parseInt((cur as any) || '0')
                }, 0)}
              </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: reduce works fine (return a number). Look at the example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-7ktxjy?file=/src/App.tsx. Probably, you got the error from somewhere place

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov Thanks for it. But typescript is throwing the error on same line. I will look into this.